# Stopwatch says <1ms but only 50 executions per second

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, stopwatch

I'm running a separate thread with a an endless loop in which I check the player's intended movement and add that to the rectangle's coordinates:

```
Thread moveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MoveThreadFunc))
{ IsBackground = true };
moveThread.Start();

private void MoveThreadFunc()
{
    int executions = 0;
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();  
    while (true)
    {
        stopWatch.Restart();

        player.lastPos = player.rec.Location; //Save last player position
        player.rec.X += player.xMovement;
        Collision(player); //Check collision and reverse move if necessary

        player.lastPos = player.rec.Location; //Save last player position
        player.rec.Y += player.yMovement;
        Collision(player); //Check collision and reverse move if necessary

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

        stopWatch.Stop();

        Debug.WriteLine(
          "elapsed: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " exec: " + executions++);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the player's rectangle moves very very slowly, even though the stopwatch reports 0ms elapsed time. The executions on the other hand match how slow it is. 
So why does the stopwatch report 0 ms then, especially since it's supposed to sleep 1ms?

Comment: You never start your stopwatch. Use `stopwatch.Start()` or `Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()`

Comment: And don't make a new stopwatch in each iteration. Reset it.

Comment: Also bear in mind that your `Debug.WriteLine` will be fairly slow.

Comment: And last but certainly not least, keep in mind that `Thread.Sleep(1)` will almost certainly sleep more than a millisecond, since it involves giving control back to the scheduler, which may not re-schedule the thread for a while.

Comment: If you want to animate anything, use a timer. In WPF a *far* better option is to use the built-in animation capabilities

Comment: Default resolution for `Sleep` is about 50 milliseconds - that is, Sleep(1) typically sleeps for that long. This has been covered many times here on SO.

Comment: @canton7 Works well with stopwatch.Restart() too, thanks

Comment: Anyway, since the code has been updated to show restarting the stopwatch, does it still report 0ms after that change? Because it really shouldn't, because of the Sleep().

Comment: @MatthewWatson looks like he vandalized his own question, editing it to fix the code